# Word 2016 - Does Word always default back to a hanging indent?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

Every time I type a new paragraph in a new document, Word 2016 always defaults back to a hanging indent, and so every time I will have to turn off the indent by right clicking, Paragraph... > Indentation > Special > None. Is there any way to make it so it no longer does this?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have changed - mistakingly - something in the default Word template.

To reset it:

1. Close **Word**
2. Go to the folder **C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates** (replace `<yourusername>` with your own username)
3. Delete the file **Normal.dotm** that is in that folder
4. Start Word again and it should be reset to the normal behavior